# Explain how the proof is done

Tags: matrices, induction

A solution of matrix problem appears to be as follows

[image]

some one explain the following in the solution

why is A cube is eliminated and fourth power of A is obtained?

In the seventh line
[image]

In the third term why the power of A is not expressed in variable but in a constant?

Why it is again multiplied by square of A and fourth power of A is eliminated?

someone help me please

Comment: What  formula is supposed to be proved?

Comment: In answer to your first question, when you multiply by $A$, you get an equation that has $A^3$ in it.  But you already know $A^3$ from eq. (i), so just substitute it in.

Comment: Why do the third term's power (power of A) is considered to be a constant despite to be declared as a variable in relation to p, as done to other terms(like abA , the first term A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following from what  @bob.sacamento wrote you will notice that:
$$
\begin{align}
A^2(A^2-abI) &= A^4-abA^2 \\
&= abA^2+A^3-abA -abA^2\\
&= abA+A^2-abI-abA \\
&=A^2 -abI
\end{align}
$$
with the help of this identity the inductive step follows easily. thus if
$$
A^p-A^{p-2}-A^2+abI =0
$$
we may write this as:
$$
A^{p-2}(A^2-I) = A^2 - abI
$$
multiplying by $A^2$ and using the result above gives:
$$
A^p(A^2-I) = A^2 - abI
$$

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of what formula has to be proved, but here's how it can be proved:

*First question:*

Multiply the first equality:
$$A^3=ab A+A^2-ab I$$
by $A$:
$$A^4=ab A^2+A^3-abA,$$
and add, simplifying what has to be simplified:
$$A^4=abA^2+A^2-abI.$$

*Second question:*

Likewise, multiply:
$$A^p-abA^{p-2}-A^2+abI=0$$
by $A^2$:
$$A^{p+2}-abA^p-A^4+abA^2=0$$
and add $A^4-abA^2-A^2+abI=0$ ($1$st equation).

Comment: But why it is done only considering the even number (4, p , p+2):

Comment: I have no idea, as you didn't say what formula was to be proved. All I can say is that there is some induction stepping from $p$ to $p+2$, hence probably different conclusions according to whether $p$ is even or odd.